# TinyMCE toolbar selects not appearing in custom toolbar

Tags: tinymce

I am installing a new TinyMCE instance into a textarea.  I am loading it using their cdn, and have registered an API Code, and registed my website on the dashboard.  It works and loads tinyMCE correctly until I try to modify the toolbars to add the select options.

To be more clear, when I load with no configuration, I see a "Paragraph" Dropdown with the various Headings, Blocks etc.  However when I try to load examples, or customize my own, I do not see those options.

Using this configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#content',
    plugins: 'fullscreen, link, image, table, code, lists, emoticons, advlist, charmap, searchreplace, codesample ',
        
    toolbar: [
      'undo redo | forecolor backcolor | formatting | align |  numlist bullist | blockquote | link | image | table | code | template | symbol | searchreplace ',
      'undo redo | sizeselect | styleselect | formatselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect | fullscreen '
    ],
    toolbar_groups: {
      formatting: {
        icon: 'bold',
        tooltip: 'Formatting',
        items: 'bold italic underline | superscript subscript | codesample'
      },
      align: {
        icon: 'align-left',
        tooltip: 'Alignment',
        items: 'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify'
      },
      symbol: {
        icon: 'insert-character',
        tooltip: 'Symbol',
        items: 'emoticons | charmap'
      }
    }
});
```

On the second toolbar, I only see icons for undo, redo and fullscreen.  None of the selects render.

Comment: What TinyMCE version are you using? If you're using TinyMCE 6 then the toolbar buttons were renamed: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/#things-we-renamed. So in that case, you'd need to use something like this instead: `'undo redo | sizeselect | styles | blocks | fontfamily | fontsize | fullscreen'`. I'm not sure what `sizeselect` is though, as that isn't a builtin TinyMCE toolbar button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configuration should work fine if you're using TinyMCE 5. However, if you're using TinyMCE 6 then the toolbar buttons were renamed: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/#things-we-renamed. So in that case, you'd need to use something like this instead: `'undo redo | sizeselect | styles | blocks | fontfamily | fontsize | fullscreen'`.